# How do I render using VBOs?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to render a hemisphere in OpenGL, the problem that the hemisphere isn't rendered at all, only part of it. I initialize it, then at each frame I draw it using the following code. I'm trying to use a VBO for drawing it.

```
void Jellyfish::Init_HemiSphere(const float radius, const int segments )
{

    m_iSegements = segments;    
    m_fVerts= new float[(segments+1)*2*3];
    m_fNormals= new float[(segments+1)*2*3];
    m_fTexCoords = new float[(segments+1)*2*2];


    for( int j = 0; j < segments / 2; j++ )
    {
        float theta1 = j * 2 * 3.14159f / segments - ( 3.14159f );
        float theta2 = (j + 1) * 2 * 3.14159f / segments - ( 3.14159f );

        for( int i = 0; i <= segments; i++ )
        {
            Vec3f e, p;
            float theta3 = i * 2 * 3.14159f / segments;

            e.x = math<float>::cos( theta1 ) * math<float>::cos( theta3 );
            e.y = math<float>::sin( theta1 );
            e.z = math<float>::cos( theta1 ) * math<float>::sin( theta3 );
            p = e * radius;
            m_fNormals[i*3*2+0] = e.x; m_fNormals[i*3*2+1] = e.y; m_fNormals[i*3*2+2] = e.z;
            m_fTexCoords[i*2*2+0] = 0.999f - i / (float)segments; m_fTexCoords[i*2*2+1] = 0.999f - 2 * j / (float)segments;
            m_fVerts[i*3*2+0] = p.x; m_fVerts[i*3*2+1] = p.y; m_fVerts[i*3*2+2] = p.z;

            e.x = math<float>::cos( theta2 ) * math<float>::cos( theta3 );
            e.y = math<float>::sin( theta2 );
            e.z = math<float>::cos( theta2 ) * math<float>::sin( theta3 );
            p = e * radius;
            m_fNormals[i*3*2+3] = e.x; m_fNormals[i*3*2+4] = e.y; m_fNormals[i*3*2+5] = e.z;
            m_fTexCoords[i*2*2+2] = 0.999f - i / (float)segments; m_fTexCoords[i*2*2+3] = 0.999f - 2 * ( j + 1 ) / (float)segments;
            m_fVerts[i*3*2+3] = p.x; m_fVerts[i*3*2+4] = p.y; m_fVerts[i*3*2+5] = p.z;
        }

    }

    glGenBuffers(3,&SVboId[0]);
    //Vertex
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,SVboId[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(*m_fVerts)*(m_iSegements+1)*2*3,
        m_fVerts,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    // Normals
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,SVboId[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(*m_fNormals)*(m_iSegements+1)*2*3,
        m_fNormals,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);



}

void Jellyfish::drawHemiSphere( )
{

    /*glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(*m_fVerts)*(m_iSegements+1)*2*3, m_fVerts );*/

    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,SVboId[0]);
    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0 );

    glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );
    glBindBuffer(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY,SVboId[1]);
    glNormalPointer( GL_FLOAT, 0,0 );

    /*glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
    glTexCoordPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT,  sizeof(*m_fTexCoords)*(m_iSegements+1)*2*3, m_fTexCoords );
    glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );
    glNormalPointer( GL_FLOAT, sizeof(*m_fNormals)*(m_iSegements+1)*2*2, m_fNormals );*/
    for( int j = 0; j < m_iSegements / 2; j++ ) {

        for( int i = 0; i <= m_iSegements; i++ )
        {

        }

        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0,   (m_iSegements + 1)*2   );
    }



    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );


}
```

Comment: You aren't using `j` in the line `glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0,   (m_iSegements + 1)*2   );`, might that be the/a problem?

Comment: might be, but how do I use it?

Comment: Start with a working example, them move on from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `sizeof` is invalid. It only works like this on fixed-size arrays. Instead of:

```
sizeof(m_fVerts)
```

Use:

```
sizeof(*m_fVerts) * (segments+1)*2*3;
```

Comment: @Same Hocevar
That made something to be appeard on screen, but just a mess of triangles. I bet there are other calculations wrong in the glDrawArrays ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh are you really drawing a triangle strip? I'd try `GL_TRIANGLES` instead of `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` as a next step.

Comment: ,Thanks for the reply. I did your suggestion, but still I see a cylinder, a not a full hemi-sphere. 
Is the drawing code correct? 
for( int j = 0; j < m_iSegements / 2; j++ ) {
  glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0,   (m_iSegements + 1)*2   );
 }

Comment: @AhmedSaleh It's because you need to take Eric's suggestion into account, too; you loop over `i` and `j` yet only fill an array of size `segments+1` vertices; your arrays need to be of size `(segments+1)*(segments/2)` and use both `i` and `j` in the index computation.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but still now working 
for( int j = 0; j < m_iSegements / 2; j++ ) {

  for( int i = 0; i <= m_iSegements; i++ )
  {
  glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, j,   (m_iSegements + i)*2   );
  }
 }

Comment: @AhmedSaleh There should be only one `glDrawArrays` call. It's the filling of the arrays that should use `i` and `j` indices. You should update your question with your updated code.

Comment: Dear Sam, I have updated the code in the post